# Is Android a sand-boxed environment?

Tags: android, linux

I have not developed for Android and need a platform for a linux-oriented application. The application requires access to the linux command line.

I have read some descriptions of the Android OS, but it is not really clear to me from those descriptions to what extent Android is "sand boxed" meaning that the user is prevented from accessing the underlying Linux OS.

Can I get access to a Linux command line in normal (unmodified) Android environment and run, for example, bash scripts, vim, and do other normal Linux activities?

By an "unmodified" environment, I mean Android out of the box used in a normal way the way a user would use it. For example, getting access to a command line by "rooting" it or taking complicated steps to circumvent the manufacturer's security processes does not help me in this application.